# Executing `mvn test` multiple times on jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have set up different `mvn` profile to post process results on jenkins. I have added `Execute Shell` twice under build section and each `Execute Shell` has following `mvn` command respectively -

`mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng1.xml`

`mvn test -PotherOutputDir -DsuiteXmlFile=testng2.xml`

On building the job only first maven command is executed. Can not I execute two `mvn test` one after another?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating shell script and keep multiple maven commands in it.
Invoking this shell script from jenkins invokes multiple maven command.
Though I am yet curious to know why I can not invoke multiple maven commands from with in jenkins.